# Background event in react native application

Tags: react-native, expo

I was wondering if there’s anything that could trigger an event in the background in react-native.

I’ve created my project with CRNA(I cannot use native code until I detach from expo and thus cannot have the android or ios folders.)
In my case, I need the data to be sent to firestore database at a particular time.

can anyone help me with this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You would need a native module to do this as expo does not support background events at this time.

Could your requirements be solved with a server function? Or do you need to send data on the device, such as latitude/longitude? The only alternative I can think of is sending the data ahead of time to a server and then have that server send the message to firestore at a particular time.

Answer (score 0):

Could use a bit more information, but this is possible if use redux with redux saga, and dispatch an action from your container component whenever you need to set the data on firestore. Your saga should handle the setting of the data.